# Weird exception thrown in python when called customized profiler

Tags: python, profile

I wrote a profiler demo like below:

```
# python version is 2.7.10
import inspect

def _profiler(frame, event, arg):
    print 'name:', frame.f_code.co_name
    print 'is_function:', inspect.isfunction(arg)


import sys

sys.setprofile(_profiler)

def orz():
    print 'why?'

orz()
```

Then I got out put like this:

```
name: orz
is_function: False
why?
name: orz
is_function: False
name: <module>
is_function: False
name: _remove
is_function:Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isfunction'" in <function _remove at 0x7fb32707c668> ignored
```

This very confuse me. This problem caused by `inspect.isfunction`. I've tried using many other modules in function `_profile`, they all got the same error:

```
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'XXX'" in <function _remove at XXX> ignored
```

If I not use any module in `_profiler` then the programme runs just fine.

Why?

Comment: Apparently, adding `sys.setprofile(None)` to the end of your code removes that exception. I didn't pry into the code yet, but it seems like it's trying to remove functions after they're executed but since the stack is empty, it's trying to remove nothing (or something of that sort)

Comment: you seems right. I've noticed the built-in profile package did what you said. I will try it right now.

Comment: Let me know if that answers what you're looking for so that i can post the answer.

Comment: I've tried, you are right. And how do you know this, are there some docs refer to this? thx for replying.

Comment: I didn't see this in the docs, though `sys.setprofile()` is documented here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html. I realized that you can pass any profiles, even an empty one (which will do nothing) since the `setprofile` function must receive a single argument. Please confirm the answer if you're satisfied with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, adding `sys.setprofile(None)` to the end of your code removes that exception. I didn't pry into the code yet, but it seems like it's trying to remove functions after they're executed but since the stack is empty, it's trying to remove nothing